# cygwin 4 bash -c pwd returning different values depending on current working dir

Tags: windows, bash, shell, cygwin

I upgraded from cygwin 3 to 4.
Now I have the following strange behaviour that I did not experience before:

I have cygwin installed in `c:\Tools\cygwin`.
`bash -c pwd` produces different output when started from `c:\Tools\cygwin` than from any other dir:

```
c:\Tools>cygwin\bin\bash -c pwd
/cygdrive/c/Tools

c:\Tools>cd cygwin

c:\Tools\cygwin>bin\bash -c pwd
/
```

This is problematic for me because until now I bundled required cygwin binaries in a bin subdirectory to execute shell scripts on Windows.
That is I had batch files that invoke the shell script via `bin/bash -f myscript.sh`.

And these shell scripts do things like `cd ..` which does not work now as the current working dir is `/`!

A workaround is to move cygwin one subdirectory deeper, but I'd like to understand why cygwin behaves like this.

[EDIT]:

It gets even better:

```
c:\Tools\cygwin>cd bin

c:\Tools\cygwin\bin>bash -c pwd
/usr/bin
```

And `ls` when starting from `c:\Tools\cygwin` shows the right content:

```
c:\Tools\cygwin>bin\bash -c "/bin/ls -l | /bin/head -5"
total 313
-rw-r--r--  1 robert.panzer root          53342 Oct 10 13:24 Cygwin-Terminal.ico
-rwxr-xr-x  1 robert.panzer root             63 Oct 10 13:24 Cygwin.bat
-rw-r--r--  1 robert.panzer root         157097 Oct 10 13:24 Cygwin.ico
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 robert.panzer Domain Users      0 Oct 10 13:22 bin
```

Comment: Good puzzle! Can any other `cygwin` user duplicate this issue? And @RobertPazer, does the `/bin/ls -l` output support that the `cd cygwin` has really taken you to `/` ? Good luck.

Comment: Exactly the same for me (except my paths: S:\ first then S:\cygwin) with my cygwin 1.7.17.

Comment: I can not believe this is new nor this is a bug because `S:\>cygwin\bin\cygpath S:\ ` gives `/cygdrive/s` to me and `S:\>cygwin\bin\cygpath S:\cygwin` gives `/`. It is perfectly consistent with the `pwd` command. It is just the path translation that performs cygwin.

Comment: At least I did not experience this with an older version of cygwin that packaged bash 3. So sth must've changed wrt this behavior. The behavior is consistent but I don't find it logical. It feels like a chroot environment.

Comment: (I find it logical because I have never seen what cygwin is apart a chroot environment with (ported?) executables for each commands.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you upgraded from the Cygwin 1.5.x series (using Bash 3.x) to the 1.7.x series (using Bash 4.x).

There is nothing surprising in Cygwin's behaviour. What surprises me is that it used to do something different.

Your Cygwin uses your `c:/Tools/cygwin` as its Unix root directory `/`. Everything inside this is part of the Unix filesystem, so the drive letter stuff is omitted. Everything else outside `c:/Tools/cygwin` is available under the `/cygdrive/<driveletter>` mount points.

And now to the `/usr/bin` stuff. Cygwin's `/bin` folder is sort of a hardlink to `/usr/bin`. All the executables are in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Yes, I got the version numbers wrong. My intention was to upgrade to a bash that is not vulnerable to shellshock. But fact is that it worked for a decade! like this before and with this upgrade the behavior changed.